# Array support in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

Can I store ARRAY column types (e.g. in [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)) in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 4):

CockroachDB now supports the `ARRAY` data type since v1.1 (released Oct 2017).

You can create an array column by adding square brackets to any data type or by using the term `ARRAY`

```
CREATE TABLE names (list STRING[]);
INSERT INTO names VALUES (ARRAY['Bertram', 'Wilberforce', 'Wooster']);
SELECT * FROM names;
+-------------------------------------+
|                list                 |
+-------------------------------------+
| {"Bertram","Wilberforce","Wooster"} |
+-------------------------------------+
(1 row)
```

Details can be found here in the docs: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/array.html

Answer (score 2):

CockroachDB doesn’t support arrays yet, but you can follow our progress on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/2115).

Answer (score 0):

As in 2022 Dec, CockroachDB support arrays - an ordered collection of values of the same type.

#### Creation of Array Columns

To create an array column in a CockroachDB table, we can use

1. Appending square bracket (`[]`) to any non-array data type.
2. Adding the term `ARRAY` to any non-array data type.

The size of an `ARRAY column is variable but it is recommended to keep value under 1 MB to ensure performance, otherwise performance may be affected.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (
    id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    numbers INT ARRAY
);

CREATE TABLE my_table2(
    id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    numbers INT[]
);
```

#### Insertion of Records Into A Table with Array Column

We can insert arrays into thess tables using `ARRAY[...]` syntax.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table1(id, numbers) VALUES(1, ARRAY[1,2,3]);
INSERT INTO my_table2(id, numbers) VALUES(1, ARRAY[4,5,6]);
```

#### Accessing All Values Or Individual Value from An Array Column

```sql
SELECT * from my_table1;
```

The output is:

```
  id | numbers
-----+----------
   1 | {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

We use square bracket (`[]`) to access 1-indexed array column.

```sql
SELECT numbers[1] from my_table2;
```

The output is:

```
  id | numbers
-----+----------
   1 |       4
```

#### Accessing An Array Column with Containment Queries

The two containment operators are:

1. `<@` - is contained by
2. `@>` - contains

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE numbers <@ ARRAY[1,2,3];
```

The output is:

```
  id | numbers
-----+----------
   1 | {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE numbers <@ ARRAY[1,2,3,4];
```

The output is:

```
  id | numbers
-----+----------
   1 | {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table2 WHERE numbers @> ARRAY[4];
```

The output is:

```
  id | numbers
-----+----------
   1 | {4,5,6}
(1 row)
```

#### Appending An Element to An Array Column

```sql
UPDATE my_table1 SET numbers = array_append(numbers, 4) WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * from my_table1;
```

The output is:

```
  id |  numbers
-----+------------
   1 | {1,2,3,4}
(1 row)
```

See more from https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/array.html